# Aura method is not a function issue for dynamic component creation

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Creating ModalContent component dynamically on 'Generate Modal Content' button click. When click on 'Call Aura Method' button calling the ModalContent's test method function using aura:method is working fine at very first time. When i do the same process again, i'm getting [contentCmp.testMthd is not a function].
[image]

Instead of creating dynamically, when i used same component in markup its working as expected. What is actually causing here?

**GenerateChildContent.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
        <aura:attribute name="hasChildCmp" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

        <div aura:id="createCmp">

        </div>

        <lightning:button label="Generate Modal Content" onclick="{!c.generateCmp}"/>
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.hasChildCmp}">
            <lightning:button label="call Aura Method" onclick="{!c.callAuraMethod}"/>
        </aura:if>

    </aura:application>
```

**GenerateChildContentController.js**

```
({
    generateCmp : function(cmp, event, helper) {

        $A.createComponent(
            "c:ModalContent",
            {
                "aura:id" : "contentCmp"  
            },
            function(modalboady, status, errorMessage){
                if(status  === "SUCCESS"){
                    var createCmp = cmp.find("createCmp");
                    createCmp.set("v.body", modalboady);
                    cmp.set("v.hasChildCmp", true);
                }else{
                    console.log("error::", errorMessage);
                }
            }
        );
    },
    callAuraMethod : function(cmp, event, helper){
        var contentCmp = cmp.find("contentCmp");
        if(contentCmp){
            contentCmp.testMthd();
        }

    }
})
```

**ModalContent.cmp**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="hasAuraMthdCalled" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <div> Modal content render </div>
    Aura method Called : {!v.hasAuraMthdCalled}
    <aura:method name="testMthd" action="{!c.testMethod}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**ModalContentController.js**

```
testMethod : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set("v.hasAuraMthdCalled", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you click on the component after first time, it returns an array instead of a Object. This is probably a known issue with dynamic component creation.

To resolve this issue, replace:

```
contentCmp.testMthd();
```

with:

```
[].concat(contentCmp)[0].testMthd();
```

---

Note the debug statement `console.log("contentCmp", contentCmp);` after logging `contentCmp`:

[image]